NLP models to classify short text based on language style
I am conducting branding research on restaurant names to see what impact the names may have on restaurant popularity. Brand names are such as:
["Miller's Ale House", "Portillo's & Barnelli's Chicago",
       'Hungry Crowd', "Trader Joe's", 'La Canasta',
       'MOOYAH Burgers, Fries & Shakes', 'Leyla',
       "Franklin's Cafe - Griffith Park", 'Quiadaiyn Restaurant',
       'Nerds' Cafe', 'Hard Rock Cafe']

I'd like to quantitatively score the brand names based on semantic/style features such as:

formal <--> informal
masculine <--> feminine
contemporary language <--> Shakespearean/literary language
humorous language <--> dry language
etc

Are there pre-trained NLP models available that can do this kind of classification task?
